# Windows service always "Starting"

Tags: c#, windows-services

I've got an app which I've tested as working as a console application.
I've now converted this to a Windows service, installed it, run it, and it still does it job.

However, it always has a status of `Starting`.  There doesn't seem to be any logical flag to set on the `ServiceBase`.

I've setup the service with a `bool isRunning` flag, and the program runs within a
`while (isRunning) {}` block.

Comment: It sounds like you've got the 'while' loop running in the OnStart() event, meaning that it never exits. Is this possibly the issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you blocking the return of `OnStart`?

Normally one would spawn a thread from there to do the work, and let the method return.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you are not handing off the run in the startup phase.

```
  static void Main()
  {
     ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
     ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new myservice() };
     AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
     currentDomain.UnhandledException += UnknownExceptionHandler;
     Run(ServicesToRun);
  }
```